# How to raise a page fault

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

I want to generate a page fault intentionally even if the page table entry already exists.

So I cleared a `_PAGE_PRESENT` bit to generate a page fault.

Here's the kernel code I wrote:

```
pte = get_locked_pte(mm, addr, &ptl);
entry = *pte;
entry = pte_clear_flags(entry, _PAGE_PRESENT);
set_pte_at(mm, addr, pte, entry);
pte_unmap_unlock(pte, ptl);
flush_tlb_range(vma, vma->vm_start, vma->vm_end);
```

However, this code does not work. The page fault I intended does not occur. I want to know exactly how I can trigger a page fault.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to write kernel code, or user-land code?

Comment: Are you writing kernel code to trip a page fault in user-land code?

Comment: The above code is the kernel code. In the above code, "addr" is the address of user space.

Comment: @JungsikChoi how do you check it doesn't occur?

Answer (score 0):

@Jungsik Choi, when you set NOT PRESENT flag for present pages you corrupt the page table entry, In fact changing a flag to NOT PRESENT makes nothing, but only changing the flag. So your pages are still present in fact. By setting NOT PRESENT flag in this way you will corrupt PTE, not induce the page fault.

if you want to observe the page fault, you need to force reads from disk. The following code maps the file given on the command-line, telling the kernel it doesn't need it; if the file is large enough (pick a large file in /usr/bin), you'll always get major page faults:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  struct stat stats;
  fstat(fd, &stats);
  posix_fadvise(fd, 0, stats.st_size, POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED);
  char * map = (char *) mmap(NULL, stats.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("Failed to mmap");
    return 1;
  }
  int result = 0;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < stats.st_size; i++) {
    result += map[i];
  }
  munmap(map, stats.st_size);
  return result;
}
```

There isn't much in the way of error handling, this is just to demonstrate the idea. On my system,

```
gcc majorfault.c -o majorfault && /usr/bin/time -v ./majorfault /usr/bin/git-annex
```

always produces 154 major page faults.